# How to add a Scrollbar in Listbox in a Grid in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to XAML and I cant seem to figure this out. I want a two column page that is docked (in winforms term) to its container. The first column has a listbox and I want this to automatically show scrollbar when needed. I was able to do so but only if I set the Height or MaxHeight of the ListBox. My problem with that is the listbox wont grow in size anymore when the main windown/form is resized. What I want is to dock the listbox to the first column so it will resize when the form is resized and show a scrollbar when needed.

Here is the code the does not show a scrollbar:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">

        <ListBox x:Name="lstView"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  Margin="10">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code that shows a scrollbar but has a fixed height.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">

        <ListBox x:Name="lstView"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 Height="200"
                  Margin="10">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Try changin row height to "*" instead of "Auto" and remove the listbox height

Comment: put a canvas with height and width inside a stackpanel and put the listbox inside the canvas

Comment: I tried but behaves the same. no scrollbar when the height in ListBox is not specified. if I specify the height the listbox doesnt grow.

Comment: @doms you changed row height to "*" in grid ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis I changed the RowDefinition Height of the grid.

Comment: @doms you changed the height to what ? try to put the Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" to listview along with that and remove the stackpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with scroll bar visibility when using a `StackPanel`. I think it is because the StackPanel is always as big as it needs to be to contain all of its children. Try reorganizing the layout to remove the StackPanel (use a **`Grid`** instead) and see if that helps.

Comment: I see!! thanks! I removed the stackpanel and it works now as I expect it should be!

Comment: Well you can Upvote and Accept it as answer as it is working as expected. :)